# JQuery: suma de valores de una columna

Tags: php, jquery

Tengo un problemilla con JQuery, no entiendo porque suma bien a veces y a veces mal.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
//Mi codigo para calcular es el siguiente:

var sum = 0;
$('.subtotal').each(function() {
  sum += parseFloat($(this).text());
});
$('#resultado_total').val(sum.toFixed(2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped ">
  <tr>
    <th class='text-center'>Estado </th>
    <th class='text-right'>Total</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='text-center'>
      <?php echo $estado;?>
    </td>
    <td class='text-right subtotal'>
      <?php echo number_format($total,2);?>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

A la espera su apoyo! gracias de antemano!

Comment: Ojo con el separador de miles, en realidad estás sumando 505 + 550 + 1. Tu separador de miles está funcionando como separador de decimales. Cómo son los datos en origen antes de sumar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es la coma en los numeros.  Debes de eliminarla y luego sumar.  Algo asi:

```js
var sum=0;
$('.subtotal').each(function() {  
 sum += parseFloat($(this).text().replace(/,/g, ''), 10);  
}); 
$('#resultado_total').val(sum.toFixed(2));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped ">
<tr>
<th class='text-center'>Estado </th>
<th class='text-right'>Total</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='text-center'></td>
<td class='text-right subtotal'>550.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='text-center'></td>
<td class='text-right subtotal'>1,050.00</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="text" id="resultado_total"></input>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! excelente observacion y analisis!